# JSON To Html Table With Merged Row For Each 2 Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say, I have an Array of object:

```
var jsonData = [{
    "Mass": "3",
    "Force": "3.1",
    "Acceleration": "3"
}, {
    "Mass": "3",
    "Force": "4.1",
    "Acceleration": "3"
}, {
    "Mass": "4",
    "Force": "4.1",
    "Acceleration": "4"
}, {
    "Mass": "4",
    "Force": "4.1",
    "Acceleration": "4"
}, {
    "Mass": "0",
    "Force": "0",
    "Acceleration": "0"
}, {
    "Mass": "0",
    "Force": "0",
    "Acceleration": "0"
}];
```

> What I want is to convert this JSON to a table like this for **each of
>   2 objects serially** where Mass and Acceleration cells are merged.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce` method and `%` operator to add element to an array on every 2nd element and then based on that new array you can build table.

```js
var jsonData = [{"Mass":"3","Force":"3.1","Acceleration":"3"},{"Mass":"3","Force":"4.1","Acceleration":"3"},{"Mass":"4","Force":"4.1","Acceleration":"4"},{"Mass":"4","Force":"4.1","Acceleration":"4"},{"Mass":"0","Force":"0","Acceleration":"0"},{"Mass":"0","Force":"0","Acceleration":"0"}]

const result = jsonData.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
  // when index is 0, 2, 4 ... (every 2nd)
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    // get also the next element 1, 3, 5
    const next = a[i + 1];
    // create a copy of current element and force as array
    const obj = { ...e, Force: [e.Force] }
    // if there is next element push its force to array
    if (next) obj.Force.push(next.Force);
    // push that new object to accumulator
    r.push(obj)
  }

  return r;
}, []);

const table = $('table');
const thead = table.find('thead');
const tbody = table.find('tbody');

Object.keys(result[0]).forEach(key => {
  thead.append($('<th>', {
    text: key
  }))
})

result.forEach(e => {
  const row = $('<tr>');
  row.append($('<td>', {
    text: e.Mass
  }));
  const force = $('<td>');
  e.Force.forEach(f => {
    const forceRow = $("<tr>");
    forceRow.append($('<td>', {
      text: f
    }));
    force.append(forceRow);
  });
  row.append(force);
  row.append($('<td>', {
    text: e.Acceleration
  }));
  tbody.append(row)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems like this is working cool. Can you just add some little explanation on how you reduced jsonData to result? It seems a bit difficult to understand. Thanks.